# Get Wordpress Post ID in JQuery file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, scroll

The following Wordpress loop creates several textblocks on a page:

```
<?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();?>
    <div class="col-md-<?php echo $column_width_input = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'column_element_grid_class_meta_box', true ); ?>"> 
        <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="textblock dicon" data-animation="<?php echo $animation_type_input = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'animation_element_grid_class_meta_box', true ); ?>" data-delay="1">
            <div class="dicon discipline-icon"><i class="fa fa-comment-o fa-2x"></i></div>          
                <h4 class="text-center"><?php echo the_title(); ?></h4>
                <p class="text-center"><?php echo the_content(); ?></p>
           </div>
           <!-- END #post -->
    </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

I am trying to write a script that will animate a particular text block .textblock with a particular animation (each textblock has a different animation). I figured that I'll use the post ID to target a textblock (**id="post-"**) but I'm not sure how to use **the_ID();** in the JS file. I have seen the rel attribute used to do this but is is not currently working for me. Here is what I have so far which only applies the same animation to all the text boxes:

```
var topOfOthDiv = $(".textblock").offset().top;
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if($(window).scrollTop() > topOfOthDiv - 400) { //scrolled past the other div?
            $(".textblock").addClass('animated ' + $(".textblock").data('animation'));
        }
    });
```

Comment: Do you want to animate each div only for once when you scroll down the page?

Comment: hows you want to detect the post_id on page load or on some event?

Comment: @Kaleem Sajid - Yes, I want to trigger the animation of each div as I scroll down the page. Do I need some type of unique identifier to target each div in JQuery? Am I thinking along the right lines?

Answer (score 3):

You could have a hidden input, and get it through js like this:

**HTML:**

```
<input type="hidden" id="post_id" value="<?php the_ID() ?>">
```

**Javascript:**

```
post_id = $("#post_id").val();
```

Comment: I'll give this a try, but is there not a cleaner way to achieve this? I'd prefer to avoid stacking hidden input fields in the HTML. Thanks.